# Python - getting just the difference between strings

Tags: python, python-2.7, difflib

What's the best way of getting just the difference from two multiline strings?

```
a = 'testing this is working \n testing this is working 1 \n'
b = 'testing this is working \n testing this is working 1 \n testing this is working 2'

diff = difflib.ndiff(a,b)
print ''.join(diff)
```

This produces:

```
  t  e  s  t  i  n  g     t  h  i  s     i  s     w  o  r  k  i  n  g     
     t  e  s  t  i  n  g     t  h  i  s     i  s     w  o  r  k  i  n  g     1     
+  + t+ e+ s+ t+ i+ n+ g+  + t+ h+ i+ s+  + i+ s+  + w+ o+ r+ k+ i+ n+ g+  + 2
```

What's the best way of getting exactly:

`testing this is working 2`?

Would regex be the solution here?

Comment: `b.split(a)`  .?

Comment: Damn @Chris_Rands . Never thought about that!! Nice hack.

Comment: @Chris_Rands nice hack but that's not a performant way to do it

Comment: What is the point of using `split`? Why not just `b.replace(a, '')`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
a = 'testing this is working \n testing this is working 1 \n'
b = 'testing this is working \n testing this is working 1 \n testing this is working 2'

splitA = set(a.split("\n"))
splitB = set(b.split("\n"))

diff = splitB.difference(splitA)
diff = ", ".join(diff)  # ' testing this is working 2, more things if there were...'
```

Essentially making each string a set of lines, and taking the set difference - i.e. All things in B that are not in A. Then taking that result and joining it all into one string.

Edit: This is a convoluted way of saying what @ShreyasG said - `[x for x if x not in y]`...

Comment: it's *not* the same as `[x for x if x not in y]` because `set(a)` will mess up the order of elements since it has no notion of order

Answer (score 8):

The easiest Hack, credits [@Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46453075/python-getting-just-the-difference-between-strings#comment79861902_46453075), by using `split()`.

**Note :** you need to determine which is the longer string, and use that for split.

```
if len(a)>len(b): 
   res=''.join(a.split(b))             #get diff
else: 
   res=''.join(b.split(a))             #get diff

print(res.strip())                     #remove whitespace on either sides
```

# driver values

```
IN : a = 'testing this is working \n testing this is working 1 \n' 
IN : b = 'testing this is working \n testing this is working 1 \n testing this is working 2'

OUT : testing this is working 2
```

**EDIT :** thanks to [@ekhumoro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46453075/python-getting-just-the-difference-between-strings/46453340?noredirect=1#comment79862953_46453340) for another hack using `replace`, with no need for any of the `join` computation required.

```
if len(a)>len(b): 
    res=a.replace(b,'')             #get diff
else: 
    res=b.replace(a,'')             #get diff
```

Comment: `b.replace(a, '')` is simpler, faster, and makes more sense.

Comment: Haha, love this. Another good hack. I never thought of using `split` or `replace` in such ways. Thank you @ekhumoro!!

Answer (score 5):

This is basically @Godron629's answer, but since I can't comment, I'm posting it here with a slight modification: changing `difference` for `symmetric_difference` so that the order of the sets doesn't matter.

```
a = 'testing this is working \n testing this is working 1 \n'
b = 'testing this is working \n testing this is working 1 \n testing this is working 2'

splitA = set(a.split("\n"))
splitB = set(b.split("\n"))

diff = splitB.symmetric_difference(splitA)
diff = ", ".join(diff)  # ' testing this is working 2, some more things...'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import itertools as it


"".join(y for x, y in it.zip_longest(a, b) if x != y)
# ' testing this is working 2'
```

---

Alternatively

```
import collections as ct


ca = ct.Counter(a.split("\n"))
cb = ct.Counter(b.split("\n"))

diff = cb - ca
"".join(diff.keys())
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Chris_Rands comment, you can use the splitlines() operation too (if your strings are multi-lines and you want the line not present in one but the other):

```
b_s = b.splitlines()
a_s = a.splitlines()
[x for x in b_s if x not in a_s]
```

Expected output is:

```
[' testing this is working 2']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following function:

```
def helper(a, b):

    for i, l_a in enumerate(a):
        if b == l_a:
            return i
    return -1

def diff(a, b):

    t_b = b
    c_i = 0
    for c in a:

        t_i = helper(t_b, c)
        if t_i != -1 and (t_i > c_i or t_i == c_i):
            c_i = t_i
            t_b = t_b[:c_i] + t_b[c_i+1:]

    t_a = a
    c_i = 0
    for c in b:

        t_i = helper(t_a, c)
        if t_i != -1 and (t_i > c_i or t_i == c_i):
            c_i = t_i
            t_a = t_a[:c_i] + t_a[c_i+1:]

    return t_b + t_a
```

Usage sample **print diff(a, b)**