# Difference between two strings (sentences)

Tags: python, string

I tried to compute the difference between two sentences as follows:

```
import difflib

text1_lines = "I understand how customers do their choice. Difference"
text2_lines = "I understand how customers do their choice."
diff = difflib.ndiff(text1_lines, text2_lines)
```

I would like to get a difference

but I am not getting that. What am I doing wrong ? Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Are you getting an error? What's your current output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - getting just the difference between strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46453075/python-getting-just-the-difference-between-strings)

Comment: Why not use set difference to calculate uncommon words between the string @henry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple list comprehension:

```
diff = [x for x in difflib.ndiff(text1_lines, text2_lines) if x[0] != ' ']
```

It will show you the deletions and addendums

Output:

```
['-  ', '- D', '- i', '- f', '- f', '- e', '- r', '- e', '- n', '- c', '- e']
```

(everything with a minus behind it was deleted)

Conversely, switching `text1_lines` and `text2_lines` would produce this result:

```
['+  ', '+ D', '+ i', '+ f', '+ f', '+ e', '+ r', '+ e', '+ n', '+ c', '+ e']
```

To remove signs, you can convert the above list:

```
diff_nl = [x[2] for x in diff]
```

To fully convert to a string, just use `.join()`:

```
diff_nl = ''.join([x[2] for x in diff])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do I get plain: Difference  without all the "+" signs etc. ?

Comment: `diff_nl = [x[2] for x in diff]`

Comment: Perhaps you can use set difference @henry if you want to ignore the signs ?

Comment: `diff_nl = ''.join([x[2] for x in diff])` for a pure string without lists

Comment: Very nice. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

from the [Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html):

```
import difflib
import sys

text1_lines = "I understand how customers do their choice. Difference"
text2_lines = "I understand how customers do their choice."
diff = difflib.context_diff(text1_lines, text2_lines)
for line in diff:
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Output:

```
*** 
--- 
***************
*** 41,54 ****
c  e  .-  - D- i- f- f- e- r- e- n- c- e--- 41,43 ----
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do I get plain: "Difference"  without all the extra stuff, signs etc. ?

Answer (score 1):

split the larger string with smaller string and you will get the difference.

```
if len(a) == 0:
   print b
   return
if len(b) == 0:
   print a
   return
if len(a)>len(b): 
   res=''.join(a.split(b))             #get diff
else: 
   res=''.join(b.split(a))             #get diff

print(res.strip())
```

Comment: `splitA = set(a.split(" "))` and `splitB = set(b.split(" "))` is what you mean EDIT nvm changed answer

Comment: Very nice !! Thanks a lot.

Comment: you can add that as a base condition, have updated the answer, this print anything if both strings are empty.

Answer (score 0):

Using actual `difflib`, this is how you would do it. The problem is you are getting a generator, which is kind of like a packed for loop, with the only way to unpack it being to iterate over it.

```
import difflib
text1_lines = "I understand how customers do their choice. Difference"
text2_lines = "I understand how customers do their choice."
diff = difflib.unified_diff(text1_lines, text2_lines)
```

`unified_diff` is different to `ndiff` in that it only shows what is different, where as `ndiff` shows what is both similar and different. `diff` is now a generator object, and all that is left to do is unpack it

```
n = 0
result = ''
for difference in diff:
    n += 1
    if n < 7: # the first 7 lines is a bunch of information unnecessary for waht you want
        continue
    result += difference[1] # the character at this point will either be " x", "-x" or "+x"
```

And finally:

```
>>> result
' Difference'
```